# Passing values through forms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a form application at Visual Studio 2015 in C#. First of all i've made a user login form using 2 textboxes and 1 button. All i want to do is to pass the value from the textbox that contains username to a label which is located to another form which form is called MainMenu. This is my code for the button i made to the login form:

```
private void button_login(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MainMenu username = new MainMenu();
   username.Value1 = textBox1.Text;
   this.Hide();
   MainMenu ss = new MainMenu();                
   ss.Show();
}
```

and the code for the MainMenu form that i want to pass the value is the following:

```
private string value1 = string.Empty;
    public string Value1
    {
        set { value1 = value; }
        get { return value1; }            
    }
    private void MainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label7.Text = Value1;
    }
```

As you can see i have create a property in MainMenu form that is accessible from login form so i could transfer the value from textbox1 directly in your MainMenu form. The problem is that the text in label7 remains empty during runtime and i can't understand why. Am i missing something from my code or i am doing something completely wrong ? 
Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: You set the `Value1` property in a `MainManu`,but why after that you are creating a new `MainMenu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually create two Forms: `username` and `ss`. You set `Value1` of `username`, but you show `ss` which you didn't set its `Value1`. So you should show `username`:

```
private void button_login(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MainMenu username = new MainMenu();
   username.Value1 = textBox1.Text;

   this.Hide();
   username.Show(); // and not ss.Show();
}
```

---

Also, a tip, use better names for your variables. The code below do exactly the same thing but is much more comprehensible:

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var mainMenuForm = new MainMenu();
   mainMenuForm.UserName = userNameTextBox.Text;

   this.Hide();           
   mainMenuForm.Show();
}

class MainMenu : Form
{
    // This is an "Auto-Implemented Property".
    // Auto-Implemented Properties are used as a shortcut of what you have done.
    // Google them for more information.
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    private void MainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userNameLabel.Text = UserName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`MainMenu username` and `MainMenu ss` are two distinct instances (of the same `MainMenu` class, but that's a detail).
You are setting the memeber variable `Value1` of `username` instance but you are displaying `ss` instance.
Consider this code

```
private void button_login(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MainMenu username = new MainMenu();
   username.Value1 = textBox1.Text;
   this.Hide();
   usename.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different MainMenu objects, the right code should be something like

```
   MainMenu username = new MainMenu();
   username.Value1 = textBox1.Text;
   this.Hide();               
   username .Show();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for you reply that was it after all

Answer (score 1):

Just as a completely different approach to the problem:

Another option is to create a static class in your project that will house any variables that you would like to reuse.

So lets say your static class is call Globals, after successfull login you would set the variable you require ie Globals.Username = textBox1.Text.

Then wherever you need that value again you can access it using Globals.Username.

Comment: This sound very usefull i will consider it.

Comment: I consider this a bad solution: the smaller the scope of a variable, the easier to maintain the code. And a Static class is actually a global variable,

Comment: What would the best alternative to my solution be, as this is the easiest way I have found thus far?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to pass variable values from one form to another, write the constructor of the second form accordingly and pass the value while creating the object of the second form.

```
private void button_login(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MainMenu ss= new MainMenu(textBox1.Text);
   this.Hide();            
   ss.Show();
}

class MainMenu : Form
{
    // This is an "Auto-Implemented Property".
    // Auto-Implemented Properties are used as a shortcut of what you have done.
    // Google them for more information.
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    private void MainMenu(string userName)
    {
        this.UserName = userName;
    }
}
```

Creating public properties and accessing them in another class for every instance of the class is bad practice for OOP.