# Using textbox input in another window?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, textblock

So i have been searching for an answer to my problem but i couldn't find anything helpful.

The problem is that i want the user to enter a name into a textbox and then pressing a button that opens a new window which will display the chosen name in a textblock.

i have tried using binding in my second window on the textblock:

```
{Binding Path=text, ElementName=TName}
```

and TName was the only one that was shown... nothing from the first window what i wanted.
so i'm kind of confused on how to use the input from the textbox from the first window.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TIName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" Width="120" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

this is what i use on my first window and:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=text, ElementName=TName} " VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

is what i have on my second window.

and this is the code behind the button on the first window:

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var test= new test();

        this.Close();
        test.Show();
    }
```

Thanks in advance:) any help will be welcome.

Comment: Look here maybe can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379892/passing-values-through-forms-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks Ed "test.TName.Text = this.TIName.Text;" worked! thanks for the fast help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that via binding. The elements in each window and their names are scoped to the window they're defined in; the contents of each window can have no knowledge of each other.

However, this should work:

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var test = new test();

    test.TName.Text = this.TIName.Text;

    this.Close();
    test.Show();
}
```

---

This binding:

```
{Binding Path=text, ElementName=TName}
```

Would be correct if both `TName` and `TIName` were in the same window, but with two small fixes: Property names in bindings are case-sensitive, and the `Text` property starts with an upper-case `T`. No property named `text` (all lower-case) exists on that control. Secondly, the `TextBox` is named `TIName`, not `TName`.

It would have to be like this:

```
{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=TIName}
```

But again, only if both controls were in the same window, which is not the case here.

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix ^^ wasn't expecting the fix to be 1 single line :')